# Accessing files in a remotely snakedeploy-ed workflow

Tags: snakemake

When using snakedeploy with a workflow remotely stored on github, what is the current best practice for that remote workflow to access files from its own "workflow/scripts/" or "resources/" directories?

---

E.g.: running

```sh
snakedeploy deploy-workflow --tag ${some_branch_or_tag} https://github.com/cbg-ethz/V-pipe .
```

will produce a workflow/Snakemake that point to the remote:

```yaml
configfile: "config/config.yaml"


# declare https://github.com/cbg-ethz/V-pipe as a module
module V_pipe:
    snakefile:
        "https://github.com/cbg-ethz/V-pipe/raw/${some_branch_or_tag}/workflow/Snakefile"

    config:
        config


# use all rules from https://github.com/cbg-ethz/V-pipe
use rule * from V_pipe
```

How should we modify these remote `workflow/Snakefile` and `workflow/rules/*.smk`, so they can:

- run scripts in `workflow/scripts/*.py`
- load sequences in `resources/<virus>/<reference>.fasta`
- load a JSON in `workflow/schemas/*.json` for direct manipulation
- open and load extra YAML files, e.g., `config/hiv.yaml` or `config/sars-cov-2.yaml`

?

Until now this was achieved by using `srcdir()` and then directly using its output. But this obviously breaks as srcdir can now produce URLs.

By inspecting how [validate](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/snakemake/utils.html#validate) does this, it seems to me that the the strategy is to:

- use `infer_source_file()` to infer the source file type (localfile vs. URL)
- use `workflow.sourcecache.open()` to download (or simply open) the file (with integrated caching).

So my questions are:

- is this the canonical way ? (And just isn't documented yet, because it's as recent as snakemake 6.8.1)
- is there a different best-practice that I am completely missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of snakemake version 6.8.1, the documentation got updated, and there is now an officially documented function for fetching such files:
https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#accessing-auxiliary-source-files

This [function internally](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blame/main/snakemake/script.py#L1238) does indeed rely on the infer_source / sourcecache.open sequence.

It does return a tupple with:

- the path
- the content of the file (from the cached content)
- automatic type identification
- whether file is local.